# Efficient gridview in asp.net webforms

Tags: performance, gridview, webforms, implementation

Hy guys.

As you know the gridview control is super heavy and reduces performance of the page, as the viewstate length is higher.

I'm trying to get a alternative way to not use default asp.net gridview webforms.

In asp.net mvc we can pass a model for example with Examples[] and in the view iterate over this array and build a 
grid and using a number of pages as a anchors than when clicked do a request to a one controller and retrieves json with content of the next 10 tuples in database.

My question is, what is for you guys the best way/more efficient to implement a gridview with paging in webforms?

Answer (score 1):

We use classic AJAX calls and javascript to render and filling the `gridVeiew`. We are also using the jQuery gridviews now. I am aiming at the reduction of data transfered if we are using a `asp:gridview` inside a `ajax:updatePanel`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you plan to use the fill GridView functionality, I usually prefer rendering the UI out as `HTML TABLE` using a `asp:Repeater` control.

HTH.